# How can I concatenate an `unsigned char` to an `std::string`?

Tags: c++

I am trying to concatenate an `unsigned char` to a `std::string` but it gives me an error saying "`operator+` not defined"

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
   unsigned char a = 't';
   std::string s   = "uoyriri";

   s = s + a;  // error: no match for operator
}
```

Comment: Good story. Did you look at the documentation? To see what overloads _are_ available? What did you find out?

Comment: Try `s += static_cast<char>(a);`.

Comment: @Kerrek: or if you're paranoid and don't know where the value of `a` comes from, try `s += boost::numeric_cast<char>(a)`, which will prevent badness when `a > CHAR_MAX`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` doesn't have an `operator+` overload for `char`.  You could do the following:

```
s += 't';
```

But in general, what you probably want is a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << "uoyriri";
ss << a;

ss.str();  // The resulting string
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the overhead of streams for this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Perhaps not in this simple case.  In general, though, it's far more flexible.

Comment: Well, `string` has no *member* function for `+`, but there's a free function template for `operator+` that does all sorts of string magic, including adding a single character. So both `s + 'a'` and `'a' + s` are reasonable expressions; it's just that you need the right `char` type.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the `append` method:

```
s.append(1, static_cast<char>(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the `unsigned char` to `char` and use operator `+=`.

Comment: wont casting to char remove the value.Suppose the unsigned char has a decimal value of 129 which is outside the range of 127 used by the char ,what would happen ?

Comment: @Jackwelch: `char` might be unsigned on your system.

Comment: @Jackwelch Depends how you cast it. Why is your input unsigned char?

Comment: @its because i am working on huffman coding and my characters are represented for a range up to 255

Comment: Is std::string really what you want then? It is `basic_string<char>`. Why don't you use `basic_string<unsigned char>`?

Comment: @Jack: converting an out-of-range unsigned value to a signed integer type is either UB, or else it's "implementation-defined result or implementation-defined signal", I can't remember which. In practice you usually get wraparound, in your example a value of -127. Weird implementations or high optimization levels might break something, though, so it's best to check the range.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has overloaded `+=` which you can use to do that:

```
s += a;
```

This should work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan works for me. @Nawaz I'm wondering why `operator +=(char)` exists, but `operator +(char)` doesn't...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oddly enough, `+=` works, while `+` on its own doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: OP's case is different. He is using `+`, whereas I'm using `+=` : http://ideone.com/i23MR

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I think, `+=` exists, because it mutates `this` object, but `+` ideally should return a new string, which in most cases not desirable. If you need that, then it is very trivial.